# Xamarin forms how to pass Entry value from one to class to another class List?

Tags: c#, list, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I want to pass inserted number value from page where I am inserting value to another page list and update ListView with new value.

Here is my AddCardPage xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="CardNr" Text="" Completed="Entry_Completed" Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

here is AddCardPage xaml.cs method:

```
void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = ((Entry)sender).Text; //cast sender to access the properties of the Entry
    new Cards { Number = Convert.ToInt64(text) };
}
```

Here is my CardsPage class where I am already declared some data:

```
public CardsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    base.Title = "Cards";
    List<Cards> cardsList = new List<Cards>()
    {
        new Cards { Number=1234567891234567, Name="dsffds M", ExpDate="17/08", Security=123 },
        new Cards { Number=9934567813535135, Name="Jason T", ExpDate="16/08", Security=132 },
        new Cards { Number=4468468484864567, Name="Carl S", ExpDate="17/01", Security=987 },
    };
    listView.ItemsSource = cardsList;  
        AddCard.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() => OnLabelClicked()),
        });       
}
    private void OnLabelClicked()
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new AddCardPage());
    }
```

and CardsPage xaml with ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
  <ListView.Footer> 
    <StackLayout Padding="5,5" Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <Label x:Name="AddCard" Text="Add new Card" FontSize="15" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ListView.Footer>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
          <Label Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="15" />
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How to pass inserted Entry value from page to another class List and update ListView content?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you're doing here but isn't it just simply bind the `Text` property of your `Entry` to the `Number`? `<Entry x:Name="CardNr" Text="{Binding Number}" Completed="Entry_Completed" Keyboard="Numeric" />`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes, but "Number" is in another class, so how can I bind if I didn't declared nowhere my Cards class?

Comment: Ah I see, do you use any MVVM framework or something? How do you navigate from one page to the other right now? Please update your question with the code for that.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Updated

Answer (score 0):

In the page you want to get the value change it's constructor to accept the value and pass that value from the calling page.

Eg:

```
class Page1
{
  private async void OnSomeEvent()
  {
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2("xyz"));
  }
}

class Page2
{
  public Page2(string myValue)
  {
  }
}
```